# Decide the biggest domain of definition

Tags: functions

I got the function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{\ln{(x^2-1)}}$. The task is to decide the biggest possible domain of definition to the function. How do I get there?

Comment: Try starting by finding the intervals where the function doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to deal with these sorts of questions is to ask yourself "What have I been told about the function, and how does this affect its domain?"
We always start with $\mathbb{R}$ and see what we need to exclude. We have $\frac{1}
{\text{something}}$ - when is this undefined?
There is also an $\ln(\text{something else})$. When can't we take the logarithm of a number?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the function and figure out where it is undefined. There are several different potential reasons for it to be undefined- dividing by 0 and the square root of a negative number are two examples.

For instance, to avoid dividing by $0$, you need to find where the denominator- $\ln(x^2-1)$- is zero, and exclude those points from your domain. (this is not the only step; what other problems could occur?)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln(x^2-1)}$. $\ln(x)$ must have a  strictly positive input, therefore we have $x^2-1>0\implies |x|>1$. Also note that $\frac1x$ must have a non-zero denominator, so we have $\ln(x^2-1)\neq0\implies x^2-1\neq1\implies|x|\neq \sqrt2$. Therefore our largest domain is $|x|>1,|x|\neq \sqrt2$.